# Contract transaction is different from required one in gnosis while creating transaction using the safe-sdk

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to create a transaction the following way

```
const txn: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
        to: to,
        value: '100000',
        data: '0x',
        operation: 0,
        safeTxGas: 45677,
        nonce: lastUsedNonce === null ? 0 : lastUsedNonce + 1,
        baseGas: 0,
        gasPrice: 0,
        gasToken: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        refundReceiver: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      };
    
    const tx = await safeSdk.createTransaction(txn);
      
    const txHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(tx);

    const signature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(txHash);

    const finalTxn = { 
        to: txn.to,
        value: txn.value,
        data: txn.data,
        operation: txn.operation,
        safeTxGas: txn.safeTxGas,
        nonce: txn.nonce,
        baseGas: 0,
        gasPrice: 0,
        gasToken: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        refundReceiver: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        contractTransactionHash: txHash,
        sender: ethers.utils.getAddress(currentAccount),
        signature: signature.data,
    }

    const res = await axios.post(`https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/${safeAddress}/multisig-transactions/`, finalTxn)
```

This throws the following error

```
{
    "nonFieldErrors": [
        "Contract-transaction-hash=0x392e5226031c9d588fd007068b4e6c72ae200dae79b838faabb9d0aba7c1eb52 does not match provided contract-tx-hash=0xd8ac72681d60e707a5ab2726b9afbac4bdb4d9a0f82c78b2f93ca3b854f784b0"
    ]
}
```

Is there something wrong that am doing while creating the txHash? Cause if I replace the finalTxn with the correct txHash from the error the transaction is created.

Comment: My guess is that this is related to missing chainId in the signature. The signature changed in Safe versions 1.3 but some of the tooling hasn't been updated properly.  You're not using this plugin, but the conversation possibly helps you: https://github.com/rmeissner/hardhat-safe-deployer/issues/2

Comment: Exactly, manually used the creation of contract transaction hash from what I found in the link u shared instead of the getTransactionHash from their sdk and it works. Thanks for the help @LauriPeltonen